# Pre-populate SuiteCRM Report's Fields

Tags: php, crm, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I am working with the Report module. I've created a relationship between Accounts And Report from the Accounts detail view when you click on the Report subPanel create button.

[image: Report Sub panel On Accounts Details page]

I'm redirecting to a create page (Edit View) of Report and while redirecting I'm setting up a default value for the Report name as in:  Report in view.edit.

[image: Setting Up value for Name And Reporting Module If you come from Account Detail page]

like this...

```
if($_POST!='') {
    $this->bean->chk_c='Accounts'; $this->bean->name = $_POST.'    Report'; 
}
```

And it's working fine. I also want to setup defaults fields for Display fields in FIELDS subpanel of Report as shown in the two attachments.

Any suggestion how to do this?

Thank You For your Time

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking please? It seems like you talk at length about something that is "working fine" before asking the question. The question that *I think* you're trying to ask is "how can I pre-populate a SuiteCRM Report's display fields?"

Comment: you are right :) But i thought it will be good to explain the full scenario

Comment: Matthew now can u please guide me ??                           because Display Field is populating on click of Add field Button , and on Click of Add field button they are calling insertFieldLine() function which is there in Fieldline.js file so can we use the same function in view.edit.php and pre-populate the suiteCRM report's display field ? and if it is possible can you please guide me how to achieve that ???                                                                       Thanks For Your Time

Comment: Abhi if I knew the process I'd be happy to, but I'm not familiar with SuiteCRM's reporting tools, only the underlying SugarCRM code base portion of it. I would begin exeactly as you are, identify the JavaScript needed to add a field, the function and it's parameters, etc. Once you have the function to fire working in your browser's JS console, see if you can tie that back to the Create button or the quick-create/quick-edit view itself.